# How to make WPQuery custom post type work in Twig / Timber

Tags: wp-query

Im totally new to Twig and Timber. I was reading their doc and watch some tutorials however I cannot get it to work.

I have this WP Query with custom post type and ACF field:

```
    <?php
          $args = array( 'post_type' => 'what_our_clients_say', 'posts_per_page' => 2 );
          $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
          while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
              echo '<div class="what-our-client-say-single-wrapper p-relative aos-init aos-animate" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="100">';
              echo '<div class="what-our-client-say-single-wrapper-violet"></div>';
                echo '<div class="what-our-client-say-inner-wrapper p-relative">';
                echo '<div class="what-our-client-say-inner-wrapper-img"><img src="' . get_field('what_our_clients_img') . '" class="img-client img-fluid"></div>';
                echo '<div class="what-our-client-say-inner-wrapper-all-txt"><div  class="what-our-client-say-inner-wrapper-header"><h3>'.get_the_title().'</h3></div>';
                echo '<div class="what-our-client-say-inner-wrapper-txt"><p>'.  get_the_excerpt() .'</p></div><div class="what-our-client-say-inner-wrapper-who"><p>'. get_field("what_our_clients_say_who") .'</p></div>';
                echo '</div></div><a href="https://pragmaticbrains.com/case-study" target="_blank" class="button big primary-colorbg no-hover what-our-client-say-special-btn">READ MORE';
                echo '</a>';
              echo '</div>';
          endwhile;
          wp_reset_postdata(); 
      ?>
```

And when I pass it to php file it works. However when I try to make it work in .twig file it doesn''t. My main problem is not with fields or excerpt / title parts (which I convert to: {{ post.title }} but with this loop:

```
 $args = array( 'post_type' => 'what_our_clients_say', 'posts_per_page' => 2 );
          $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
          while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
(...)
   endwhile;
          wp_reset_postdata();
```

part. I would be very grateful for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think is as simple as using Timber's `Timber::get_posts()` instead of the `WP_Query` class:

```
$context['testimonials'] = Timber::get_posts( ['post_type' => 'what_our_clients_say', 'posts_per_page' => 2] );
Timber::render('whatever.twig, $context);
```

... from there you can loop through the testimonials and access ACF values via meta:

```
{% for post in testimonials %}
    <h1>{{ post.attribution }} says:</h1>
    {# more here #}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks, now it's very clear and it works!